# How to wake the android device from deep sleep using wake lock?

Tags: android, sleep

How can i wake the android device using a wakelock? Or is this not possible and must i use alarm manager?

This does not work

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK|PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "bbbb");


        wl.acquire();
        wl.release();
        }
    }, 10000);
```

Handler is used to run the following code after i have time to turn off the display.

Comment: Wakelock is intended to keep a device from going (partially) to sleep, not to wake it up.

Comment: how can i wake it up then? Everything i found in `AlarmManager` only works at a certain time and not at a certain line of code. Like, i can't have a notification wake the device using `AlarmManager`

Comment: What do you mean by _'have an notification wake the device'_? If the device is asleep, there is no way to create a notification. Please explain more what you want to wake the device up.

Comment: Yes there are ways to create notifications when the device is asleep. GoSMS does it, they also have the option to wake the device upon receiving the notification. Almost any messaging application does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use AlarmManager to wake the device up from standby. In the BroadcastReciver, acquire a wakelock as you have done in your Handler. This should work.

A note on Handlers. They work only when your device in not in standby. Once a device enters standby, Handlers are inactive until you wake the device up manually.

Comment: Crap. What i am trying to do is modify my anroid.policy.jar file of my Tablet to wake the device when you open the lid. (It has a keyboard dock) So i guess in the anroid.policy.jar, i can send the broadcast intent using the alarm manager, then have a second app that i wrote to handle the broadcast intent from the alarm manager.

Comment: yes, that should do. If you can capture the broadcast when the lid is opened, grab a full screen wake lock and you are done!

Comment: Please note that you only have 10 seconds of runtime in the BroadcastReciver context. You have to pass a Intent to a service or activity.